# CakePHP model associations table w/data and new table

Tags: cakephp, associations

I have a table(drugs) which lists all of the drugs in that table. Drugs hasOne french_information and french_information belongsTo Drugs. I would like for the users to be able to click a drug,have information about it displayed and then select french and have it bring up a view to add french information,while displaying the chosen drugs information, with fields to add french info for it and store it in the french_information table. How would I do that?

Comment: Ask a specific question about one aspect of what you're trying to do.  This isn't the place for tutorials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wouldn't.

There's no need to have the Mentor data in the Students table unless you have student data to go with it.

When a student is created, you can add it to the students table along with it's corresponding Mentor's ID.  If you'd like, you can always add a beforeSave() in your Student model to make sure that mentor doesn't already have a student attached prior to saving.

If for some reason you feel you MUST have empty data in your students table, you can always write some code in any action (to be run once) where you loop through each Mentor, build an array for $student and save it - something like this:

```
$mentors = $this->Mentor->find('all');
foreach($mentors as $mentor) {
    $this->Student->create();
    $student = array('mentor_id'=>$mentor['id']);
    $this->Mentor->Student->save($student);
}
```

Or, you could write SQL and run it directly on the database.

Comment: I'm not sure I was clear. I edited the question to be more specific. :)

Comment: It's not that it would be empty forever, just empty until a specific one was chosen, and they'd go in and edit the information for it. I think the solution gets me going in the right direction, thank you! I'll try it now.

Comment: What you meant to say is "I changed my question to ask something all-together different".  :)

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick. You'll end up with empty `student_name` fields, though.

```
INSERT INTO `students` (mentor_id) SELECT id FROM `mentors`;
```